# Object array cannot display all variables using SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

var str = "Hello, playground"

struct FianceItem: Identifiable,Codable {
    public var id: UUID = UUID()
    public var name: String
    public var childs:[FianceItem] = []
}

var root=FianceItem(name: "root")

var childA=FianceItem(name: "childA")
root.childs.append(childA)

var childB=FianceItem(name: "childB")
childA.childs.append(childB)

print(root)
```

Comment: Only root and rootA can be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`struct` is a value type. When you assign it to another variable, its value is copied.
So order matters in this case.

This line is creating a copy of `childA` and putting it into the array of `root`.

```
root.childs.append(childA)
```

When you edit the original, the copy does not have childB.

Either reorder the code like Raja Kishan's answer or use `class` instead of `struct`.

Comment: Very accurate,Thank you：）

Answer (score 0):

Change your sequence

```
let contentView = DeveloperView()

var root=FianceItem(name: "root")

var childA=FianceItem(name: "childA")

var childB=FianceItem(name: "childB")
childA.childs.append(childB)

root.childs.append(childA)

print(root)
```